# Passing json data from jsp page to ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-select2

So I am trying to make an autocomplete working with Select2 plugin and AJAX, sending and receiving(Json) data from a jsp file. So my problem is that while the AJAX is called and it sends data to the jsp file, and I have checked that the jsp file works perfectly I get this message
**Results could not be loaded.**
[image: alt]

Here is the jquery code for AJAX

```
    $("#id").select2(        {
    placeholder: 'Select an item',
    ajax: {
      url: 'autocomplete.jsp?type=dbpedia_resources',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
```

previously I was using this with the same results

```
$("#entities").select2(        {
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: "autocomplete.jsp?type=dbpedia_resources",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        delay: 250,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {

            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.text,
                        //slug: item.slug,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

And the jsp/java code is this

```
    <%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
    <%@page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="com.aylien.newsapi.*"%>
    <%@page import="com.aylien.newsapi.auth.*"%>
    <%@page import="com.aylien.newsapi.models.*"%>
    <%@page import="com.aylien.newsapi.parameters.*"%>\
    <%@page import="org.json.*"%>
    <%@page import="com.aylien.newsapi.api.DefaultApi"%>

    <%

    String type =  request.getParameter("type");
    ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();

    // Configure API key authorization: app_id
    ApiKeyAuth app_id = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("app_id");
    app_id.setApiKey("");

    // Configure API key authorization: app_key
    ApiKeyAuth app_key = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("app_key");
    app_key.setApiKey("");

    DefaultApi apiInstance = new DefaultApi();

    //String type = "dbpedia_resources";
    String term = request.getParameter("q");
    String language = "en";
    Integer perPage = 10;

    AutocompletesParams.Builder autocompletesBuilder = AutocompletesParams.newBuilder();

    autocompletesBuilder.setType(type);
    autocompletesBuilder.setTerm(term);
    autocompletesBuilder.setLanguage(language);
    autocompletesBuilder.setPerPage(perPage);

    try {
        Autocompletes result = apiInstance.listAutocompletes(autocompletesBuilder.build());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

        out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        System.out.println(result.getAutocompletes());



    } catch (ApiException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception when calling DefaultApi#listAutocompletes");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you checked your console?

Comment: @madalinivascu Yeah it doesn't show any errors

Comment: your xhr request body ?